# Summarize and NAs

Tags: r

My code has broken and it seems it's due to NAs and summarize. I did a join on two data frames and due to differences in time, there are NAs that will show up.

My join:

```
data <- dplyr::right_join(ny.t, c.p, by=c("Date", "State"))
```

My code:

```
top.5 <- data %>% group_by(State) %>% summarize(Infected = max(Deaths) + max(Positive)) %>%
arrange(desc(Infected)) %>% top_n(5)
```

How to fix?

Comment: It is all `NA` elements, what o you want as output

Comment: I am at a loss right now because the code was running fine. I brought in two files: 
ny.t <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nytimes/covid-19-data/master/us-states.csv")

and 

c.p  <- jsonlite::fromJSON("https://covidtracking.com/api/v1/states/daily.json")...

And  I did a join. It worked earlier.

Comment: Do you need `data %>% group_by(state) %>% summarise(Infected = if(all(is.na(deaths))) 0 else max(deaths, na.rm = TRUE) + max(positive, na.rm = TRUE))`

Comment: I just want to filter by the top 5 states for cases (positive and dead due to COVID).

Comment: Can you try the code on my solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could create a condition so that `if` `all` the values are `NA` in `deaths` return 0 or else return the `max` value

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
    group_by(state) %>% 
    summarise(max_deaths = if(all(is.na(deaths))) 0 else max(deaths, na.rm = TRUE),
              max_positive = if(all(is.na(positive))) 0 else max(positive, na.rm = TRUE),
             max_negative =  if(all(is.na(negative))) 0 else max(positive, na.rm = TRUE))
```

---

Or use `summarise_at`

```
data %>%
    group_by(state) %>%
    summarise_at(vars(deaths, positive, negative),
       ~ if(all(is.na(.))) 0 else max(., na.rm = TRUE))
```

Comment: My Deaths unfortunately become eliminated in some of my visuals now. Ideas why this is?

Comment: @purple_plop Here, the condition is only activated when all values of `deaths` are NA or else, it would take the `max` of `deaths` with `max` of positive i..e when all deaths are NA, it returns the `max` of 'positive'

Comment: I need the Positive, Negative, and Dead as separate variables.

Comment: @purple_plop in that case, the `+` combines everything, we can make the changes then

Comment: FYI the intention of top.5 is so that i can filter by using filter(State in %in% top.5$State)... and then everywhere else in my visuals, I must use deaths per day, etc.

Comment: @purple_plop in that case the `max` is not clear by state